# Growth of average first derivative of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Let $L_k(t)$ be the Legendre polynomials normalized so that 
$$\int_{-1}^1 L_k(t)^2\,\frac{1}{2}\,dt = 1.$$
With a few identities (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials), one can show that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 L_k'(t)\,\frac{1}{2}\,dt \;=\; \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \mbox{if $k$ is even,}\\
\sqrt{2k+1} & \mbox{if $k$ is odd,}
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
where the prime notation means "derivative." I'm wondering how general this result might be, and if anyone has experience with this? I think the average derivative of the Hermite polynomials are all zero. I wonder if all polynomials orthogonal to a symmetric weight function on a bounded interval might behave like the Legendre polynomials, i.e., 0 if $k$ is even and $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{k})$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: try to check this link mayeb help you to get the answer of your problem :http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46930-first-derivative-of--normalized--associated-legendre-polynomials#comments

Comment: The average of the derivative $P'$ of *any* polynomial $P$ on $(a,b)$ is $(P(b)-P(a))/(b-a)$.  So for example if $P$ is the Čebyšev polynomial $T_k$ then we get $0$ or $1$ according as $k$ is even or odd.  Not sure what you're claiming about the Hermite polynomials: their interval of orthogonality is $\bf R$, on which the average is a divergent integral for $k>0$.

Comment: Thanks, @NoamD.Elkies. The Chebyshev polynomials are a nice counterexample. For the Hermite polynomials, I mean averaged against a standard Gaussian weight function, like you would define their orthogonality. I think you could use the relationship you mention to prove my about zero average derivatives.